# Path-Connected Components

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

How many path-connected components does $O_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ have?

My Attempt: I believe that the answer is 2, but I'm not sure how to work with the definition and describing the path-connected components.

Comment: Can you think of a continuous map to a space with two path connected components?

Comment: @Carmeister It is not a perfect duplicate of your link (components vs. path components), but the answer covers the present question.